# Contract.create bytes array return value

Tags: smart-contracts, liquidity

I'm using liquidity lang, and define a storage:

```
type storage = {
  usersDocuments : (address,address set) big_map;
  documents: string set;
}
```

and I add in to usersDocuments https://pastebin.com/dkV4EtL2 as follows:

```
  let (op,docAddress) =
    Contract.create
      ~storage: (fileHash,userAddress,Set,Set)
      ~manager:manager
      ~spendable:false
      ~delegatable:false
      ~delegate:(None)
      ~amount:0tz (contract Document)
  in

  let userDocuments = match Map.find userAddress storage.usersDocuments with
    | None -> Set
    | Some docSotrage -> docSotrage
  in
  let userDocuments = Set.add docAddress userDocuments in
```

After that, I'm using the RPC api search from big_map, and the api returns:

```
[
    {
        "bytes": "011cd5f135e80fd8ebb6e43335b24ca6116edeba6900"
    }
]
```

How can I transform the byte array to a contract address, which is created from a smart contract?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the 'optimized' Micheline representation of an `address` value.

In the future, I think we should extend the client and RPC a bit, to make things easier here. For now...

You can see optimized encoding referenced in [parse_data](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/blob/225364d9ad201b566e2f15d47f04078e220493f0/src/proto_003_PsddFKi3/lib_protocol/src/script_ir_translator.ml#L1438) and [unparse_data](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/blob/225364d9ad201b566e2f15d47f04078e220493f0/src/proto_003_PsddFKi3/lib_protocol/src/script_ir_translator.ml#L3006) for the `address` type.

The encoding is defined in [contract_repr.ml](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/blob/225364d9ad201b566e2f15d47f04078e220493f0/src/proto_003_PsddFKi3/lib_protocol/src/contract_repr.ml#L66).

There is a 'tag' byte first:

- If the first byte is 0x00, an implicit account public key hash follows. (This, in turn, will have a curve code byte for tz1/tz2/tz3, and then the key hash itself, as defined in [signature.ml](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/blob/225364d9ad201b566e2f15d47f04078e220493f0/src/lib_crypto/signature.ml#L68).)
- If the first byte is 0x01, an originated account address follows, with an extra 0x00 byte of padding at the end.

So in your example, base58check-encoding the hex `1cd5f135e80fd8ebb6e43335b24ca6116edeba69` -- dropping the 0x01 tag and 0x00 padding bytes -- gives `KT1BDEn6wobs7tDReKkGheXAhoq278TGaNn5`.

Comment: Thanks! sorry where you decode , online service?

Comment: maybe tezos base58 encoding/decoding deserves its own question? :)